# Using a win32 DLL library on a Universal Windows App C++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, windows-10-universal

I was able to compile a dll library based by following the instructions indicated from this tutorial http://tutplusplus.blogspot.com/2011/04/c-tutorial-create-dll-in-vc-20102008.html. I compiled it and there are no problems. I also tested my dll library on an empty win32 console application solution and it compiled fine by adding the header, source file and changing the linker settings. The problem is I can't use the dll library this time on a Universal Windows App solution. I added the header and source files as well as changed the linker settings.

When I compiled the project solution it asked me to include `pch.h` to the source file of my library so I added the line `#include "pch.h"` on top.

After that, other compiler errors came up.

`'CreateFile': identifier not found` and `'SetCommState': identifier not found`

I believe the compiler for my current project solution ***recompiled everything*** again without considering the dll library's compilation. How can I make the project solution just compile its own source and header files?

Lib Header:

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

namespace nmspace
{
    class SerialPort 
    {
    public:
        static __declspec(dllexport) int connect();
    };
}
```

Lib Source:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "SimpleH.h"
#include <Windows.h>

namespace nmspace
{
    int SerialPort::connect() 
    {
        int error = 0;
        DCB dcb;

        memset(&dcb, 0, sizeof(dcb));

        dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(dcb);

        dcb.BaudRate = 57600;
        dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
        dcb.fParity = 0;
        dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
        dcb.ByteSize = 8;

        HANDLE m_serialPortHandle = CreateFile(L"COM7", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, NULL, NULL);

        if (m_serialPortHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
            if (!SetCommState(m_serialPortHandle, &dcb))
                error = 2;
        }
        else
            error = 1;

        return error;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use this DLL because it uses `SetCommState` function that is only available for desktop applications. You should lookup functions that you are trying to use in a [list of desktop APIs available for UWP applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/win32-and-com/win32-and-com-for-uwp-apps).

As for `CreateFile` it is not a function, but a macro expanding to `CreateFileA` or `CreateFileW` depending on project Unicode settings. You should use [`CreateFile2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422.aspx) instead which is available for both Desktop and UWP applications.

Comment: thanks, how about `setcommstate` for upw applications? sorry i don't want to use `serialdevice` library of uwp and wanted to create it on my own

Comment: Is `setcommstate` something different than `SetCommState`?

Comment: They are just the same. It's just `SetCommState` is not working in UWP.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer above `SetCommState` is not one of the desktop APIs available for UWP applications so there is no way to use it. And there is no workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple. WinRT doesn't support the complete WinApi! You must use the WinRT function from the [UWP Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/)

Just read the docs to [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). In the documentations you find under requirements:

> Minimum supported client Windows XP **[desktop apps only]** Minimum
>   supported server Windows Server 2003 **[desktop apps only]**

This tells you that CreateFile isn't allowed in WinRT.

AFAIK accessing a serial port from WinRT isn't possible. Just google. Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23127596/access-to-serial-port-for-windows-store-apps) that states this. Same [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/433d19c7-312d-49ed-b316-b3ed5cd21ecb/serial-port-support-in-winrt?forum=windowsdeveloperpreviewgeneral)